# How do I make the AuthorizeEndpointPath work in ASP.NET Oauth 2.0 framework

Tags: c#, oauth, owin

I currently have a website where I am trying to implement the OAuth server framework.  The website is currently a combination of Web Forms (not MVC) and Web API 2.  For the purposes of what I am trying to do, we cannot change the overall architecture of the system.

So far, I have OAuth working via the Web API for validating clients, generating access tokens, and handling refresh tokens.

The last piece I am trying to implement is the Authorize Code workflow.  This will allow us to grant access to our application so integration tools can access our APIs without having to locally store the user credentials.

My understanding of how it should function is the following:

1. User is directed to the AuthorizeEndpointPath that I define in the Startup.Auth file
2. User either sees a login page (if they don't already have an authentication cookie for the website), or they see a special page where they have to grant permission to access the account (similar to what Google has)
3. Once the user clicks the "grant" button, the OWIN middleware will process the request, and redirect them back to the original client URL that requested access

However, after all of my configuration, whenever I access the AuthorizeEndpointPath directly, the "grant access permission" page is never actually displayed.

I've ensured the following configuration, but there isn't much documentation on what the correct configuration is.

```
var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/LoginAuthorize.aspx"),
                //AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/authorize"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                Provider = new ApiAuthorizationServerProvider(),
                RefreshTokenProvider = new ApiRefreshTokenProvider(),
                AuthorizationCodeProvider = new ApiAuthoirzationCodeProvider()
            };
```

Currently the "AuthorizeEndpointPath" property maps to an actual page, where I ask the user confirmation, but that page is not being displayed at all

Through debugging, I can see the framework hits the following method even before the authorization page would be loaded

```
ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
```

I have tried to overload that method, and one of 2 things happens.  If I make a call to context.Validated();, the user is immediately redirected without the authorization page being displayed.  If don't "validate" the redirect URI, then a blank page is displayed indicating an "invalid_request".

**So the big question is how do I actually make OWIN display my custom authorization page?**

When the authorization page is finally displayed, what would I need to do when the user clicks on the "grant" button.  Is there any configuration I need to setup, or any calls to OWIN I need to make?

Also, how do I ensure the user authenticates before that page is displayed?  Do I simply have my code redirect the user to the login page if they are not logged in?  If so, how will OWIN handle the real redirect back to the client (if the user would be redirected to the authorization page once they login)?

Finally, once this is all configured properly, will I still be able to support the current OAuth workflow I have of allowing clients to manually pass in their credentials for the "token" API? The reason I ask is because we also have mobile apps that have their own sign-in screen, and will be using OAuth to connect (in addition to other web-based clients).

Answer (score 2):

I had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722767/authorizationcodeprovider-create-is-never-called-how-do-i-generate-the-authori) that turned out to be similar to yours.

So, after quite some searching online, I got some success by searching github. Apparently, `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` offers `AuthorizeEndpoint` and that method should be used for both "Hey, you're not authorized, go log in you!" as well as for "Ahh, okay you're cool, here's an authorization code.". I had expected that `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` would have two separate methods for that, but it doesn't. That explains why on github, I find some projects that implement `AuthorizeEndpoint` in a rather peculiar way. I've adopted this. Here's an example:

```
public override async Task AuthorizeEndpoint(OAuthAuthorizeEndpointContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.User != null && context.Request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var redirectUri = context.Request.Query["redirect_uri"];
        var clientId = context.Request.Query["client_id"];

        var authorizeCodeContext = new AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(
            context.OwinContext, 
            context.Options.AuthorizationCodeFormat,
            new AuthenticationTicket(
                (ClaimsIdentity)context.Request.User.Identity,
                new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"client_id", clientId},
                    {"redirect_uri", redirectUri}
                })
            {
                IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(context.Options.AuthorizationCodeExpireTimeSpan)
            }));

        await context.Options.AuthorizationCodeProvider.CreateAsync(authorizeCodeContext);

        context.Response.Redirect(redirectUri + "?code=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(authorizeCodeContext.Token));
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/account/login?returnUrl=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(context.Request.Uri.ToString()));
    }
    context.RequestCompleted();
}
```

Source: https://github.com/wj60387/WebApiOAUthBase/blob/master/OwinWebApiBase/WebApiOwinBase/Providers/OAuthServerProvider.cs

You create a separate login page at `/account/login`. What this does is sign the user in. If your WebAPI uses cookie-based authentication, you can just redirect the user back to the `AuthorizeEndpoint` again. If you use access tokens, your login page has to make a request to `AuthorizeEndpoint' with the access token to obtain an authorization code. (Don't give the access token to the third party. Your login page requests the authorization code and sends that back.) In other words, if you use access tokens then there are two clients involved in this flow.